# Core dump happens in Java native method

Tags: java, c, coredump

My project is a spring boot project and run in K8s pod. An error encountered and this is header of the log file:

```
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f116f6b1be1, pid=516, tid=0x00007f10795ef700
#
# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (8.0_121-b13) (build 1.8.0_121-8u121-b13-0ubuntu1.16.04.2-b13)
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libc.so.6+0x95bd3]  strchrnul+0x23
#
# Core dump written. Default location: /projects/core.dump
```

Then I try to get the file core.dump, its size is **5G**. And my project invoke the C native method through .so file, which doesn't include method `main` , so I cann't compile to get the `.exe` or `.out`. I don't know how to analyze the dump file after trying these method：

```
gdb [exe file] [core file](can get the exe file)
gdb java core.dump
jmap -dump:format=b,file=./2842.hprof $JAVA_HOME/bin/java core.dump
```

How can I analyze the core.dump the locate the problem?

Comment: Sorry, it should be "can not get the exe file" instead of "can get the exe file".

Answer (score 1):

Supposing you are in Windows then you can easily debug dumps with WinDbg. You can try WinDbg Preview - I am using this to debug Java core dumps.
You can download it here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/debugger-download-tools

Then just run `!analyze -v` as your first command and you get lot of useful information. I had 40G dumps so 5G should be fine.
Of course you have to choose right thread, e.g. here is stack from my thread `java.exe!main`:

[image: Java core dump stack]

Comment: Hi~My dump is generated by linux system. Can I analyze the linux dump in windows? Is it related to the system?

Comment: Sure you can. Windbg will handle it as OSNAME:  Linux

Comment: However if you want stay with GDB of course you can analyze it with GDB. Just run `gdb /opt/jdk-14/bin/java core.693` Maybe you need to provide full working path to executable java, maybe this is what you was doing wrong.

Comment: Thanks~I will try your method to see what happen.

Comment: Hi~ I install Windbg Preview and run `!analyze -v`, but it does not seems to show a crash message. I just open the dump file and run `!analyze -v`. Is there anything else I should do?

Comment: The main message:

`
EXCEPTION_RECORD:  (.exr -1)
ExceptionAddress: 000002d692c0d840
   ExceptionCode: e0534947
  ExceptionFlags: 00000000
NumberParameters: 2
   Parameter[0]: 0000000000000006
   Parameter[1]: fffffffffffffffa

FAULTING_THREAD:  0000052f

PROCESS_NAME:  java

ERROR_CODE: (NTSTATUS) 0xe0534947 - <Unable to get error code text>

EXCEPTION_CODE_STR:  e0534947

EXCEPTION_PARAMETER1:  00000006

EXCEPTION_PARAMETER2:  fffffffffffffffa

STACK_TEXT:  
00007fd4 6867d098 00007fd4 aa066428 libc_2_23+0x354
00007fd4 6867d1f0 00007fd4 a9521927 libjvm+0xa66927
`